# Custom Spring roo addon fail

Tags: spring, extjs

I have a custom spring roo addon for extjs, I put it into bundle directory and deleted cache directory but when I initiate the console by msdos I'm having the next messange just in the entrance:

```
ERROR: Bundle com.xxx.xxx.addons.extjs [7] Error starting file:/K:/Software/springsource32/springsource/spring-roo-1.2.2.RELEASE/bundle/com.xxx.xxx.addons.extjs-2.0.2.jar (org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.xxx.xxx.addons.extjs [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0:
missing requirement [7.0] package; (&(package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0))))
org.osgi.framework.BundleException: Unresolved constraint in bundle com.xxx.xxx.addons.extjs [7]: Unable to resolve 7.0: missing requirement [7.0] pack
age; (&(package=org.apache.commons.io)(version>=1.4.0)(!(version>=2.0.0)))
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.resolveBundle(Felix.java:3564)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.startBundle(Felix.java:1797)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.Felix.setActiveStartLevel(Felix.java:1192)
        at org.apache.felix.framework.StartLevelImpl.run(StartLevelImpl.java:266)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I don't know why this happend and don't know what to check, can anybody help me?

Comment: Looks like you're missing a package ...

Comment: Could be but I dont't find any way to know which libraries are conflicting.

Comment: Now I just downloaded a new spring roo version and when I try to iniciate roo console a lot of errors are generated. It's the same kind of error that a refer before. As I said, this is a new version (virgen) and I'm not include any new custom addon.